# Why is SpringApplicationBuilder.run made as thread-safe?

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, thread-safety

The following codes come from Spring Boot SpringApplictionBuidler. I know it uses double-checking to implement thread-safe. The question is that, is it necessary to make the run method thread-safe? Even other methods are not thread safe.

```
public ConfigurableApplicationContext run(String... args) {
    if (this.running.get()) {
        // If already created we just return the existing context
        return this.context;
    }
    configureAsChildIfNecessary(args);
    if (this.running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        synchronized (this.running) {
            // If not already running copy the sources over and then run.
            this.context = build().run(args);
        }
    }
    return this.context;
}
```

I have searched on the internet. What I want to know is the motive of the codes.

Comment: This doesn't look thread-safe to me because it is possible that `running` is `false` without `context` being initialized. However, I don't know the exact concurrency _requirements_ of this code. Is this code really part of Spring itself?

Comment: @dan1stmightbehappyagain, you can check this link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.0.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.java

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you look at the current sources?

The sources for the [3.2 branch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3.2.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.java#L141) don't contain this anymore:

```
    public ConfigurableApplicationContext run(String... args) {
        if (this.running.get()) {
            // If already created we just return the existing context
            return this.context;
        }
        configureAsChildIfNecessary(args);
        if (this.running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            // If not already running copy the sources over and then run.
            this.context = build().run(args);
        }
        return this.context;
    }
```

And there was a commit about 8 months ago that removed this:

> [Remove unnecessary synchronization](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/726d2e66786ad8463cfc54b3782aa58992b35475)
>
> - on AtomicBoolean in SpringApplicationBuilder
> - on SimpleFormatter
> - in a private method in FileSystemWatcher which is always called in a
>   synchronized block
> - Replaced synchronized guarded HashMap with ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Althroungh the synchronized block has been removed, it doesn't make me clear. Why does it use AtomicBoolean running variable instead of a boolean one, if the builder will not be used in the concurrent context?

Comment: Note: it was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/726d2e66786ad8463cfc54b3782aa58992b35475#diff-7bd59e0efd5070b1dd973313ed4185d50cea979ea5e67509ed5b4e4cc0013a90).

Comment: @Droopy maybe the main important thing is that it isn't created twice but it isn't supposed to be called concurrently during initialization so a NPE isn't a problem?

Comment: I know what's your meaning about NPE and have no idea about those codes.